# im getting an error and cannot find a way to solve it

Tags: java, class

I am creating a TictTacToe for my school project (object-orientated) but I ran into this problem where when I try to call the class I get an error saying "method placements in class placePiece can not be applied ton given types". I tried passing in char[][] and int into: new placePiece(char[][] GameBoard, int PlayerPiece); like this but then it gives me an error saying ";" expected and .class expected.
Like I said Im new to programming so literally anything will help.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameBoard g = new GameBoard();
        g.print();
        
        SelectPlayingPiece s = new SelectPlayingPiece();
        s.Scan();

      PlacePiece p = new PlacePiece();
       p.placements(); 
  } 

import java.util.Arrays;
public class GameBoard{

 public static void print(){
//create a game board for the user to play.
    char[][] gameBoard = {{' ','|' ,' ', '|', ' '},
                          {'-','+' ,'-', '+', '-'},
                          {' ','|' ,' ', '|', ' '}, 
                          {'-','+' ,'-', '+', '-'}, 
                          {' ','|' ,' ', '|', ' '}};      
                          
     //print gameboard 2D array.
    for ( char[] row : gameBoard){
     for ( char c : row ){
        System.out.print(c);
          }
   System.out.println();
        }
      }         
 }

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PlacePiece{
  public static void placements(char[][] gameBoard, int playerPiece){
    //game starts and player selects a column to place thier piece. 
    System.out.print("Game has begun,please enter where you would like to place (1~9):");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int placement = scan.nextInt();
  
          char piece = 'X';
          if( playerPiece == 1){
              piece = 'X';
              } else {
                piece = 'O';
            }

    switch(placement){
      case 1: gameBoard[0][0] = piece;
              break;
      case 2: gameBoard[0][2] = piece;
              break;
      case 3: gameBoard[0][4] = piece;
              break;
      case 4: gameBoard[2][0] = piece;
              break;
      case 5: gameBoard[2][2] = piece;
              break;
      case 6: gameBoard[2][4] = piece;
              break;
      case 7: gameBoard[3][0] = piece;
              break;
      case 8: gameBoard[3][2] = piece;
              break;
      case 9: gameBoard[3][4] = piece;
              break;
    }  

   }
   
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SelectPlayingPiece{  
    //allow players to pick thier playing piece.           
    
    public void Scan(){
      
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
      System.out.println("Welcome to TicTacToe! Frist, pick your playing piece: Type 1 to be X and type 0 to be O ");
      int playerPiece = scan.nextInt();
    
      char player1 = 'X';
      if( playerPiece == 1){
      System.out.print("player 1 is X!");
        player1 = 'X';
        } else{
       System.out.print("Player 1 is O!");
         player1 = 'O';
      } 
   }  
}
```

Comment: Can you mark the problematic line?

Comment: @tibetiroka `p.placements();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `placements` method on PlacePiece takes `char[][]` and `int` as arguments. You're calling it without any arguments, which results in your first error.

You're then trying to pass these arguments not to the `placements` method, but the constructor of PlacePiece. Since The PlacePiece class only contains a default constructor (since you didn't explicitly provide one), this also fails.

Try replacing this part of your code:

```
PlacePiece p = new PlacePiece();
p.placements();
```

with something like this:

```
PlacePiece p = new PlacePiece();
p.placements(gameBoard, playerPiece);
```

You'll have to create a variable called `gameBoard` of type `char[][]` and a variable called `playerPiece` of type `int` before this obviously.

Unrelated to your problem, but look into static methods and how they're called. Since you're using only a static method on all of your classes, you could just do something like `PlacePiece.placements(gameBoard, playerPiece)` instead of creating an instance first.

Comment: isn't char [][] = gameBoard and int playerPIece already declared? you said I would have to create a variable on both. Im a little confused on that part.

Comment: @Dankkoo not in that context. You're declaring those in as local variables in a (static) method of an entirely different class, you can't access those from inside your Main class.